# Overload is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function

```
type QueryGrouprequestsOverloadI = {
  (
    variables: ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
    limit?: number,
    returnPartion?: false
  ): Promise<ListGrouprequestsQuery['listGrouprequests']['items']>
  (
    variables: ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
    limit?: number,
    returnPartion?: true
  ): Promise<ListGrouprequestsQuery['listGrouprequests']>
}

export const queryGrouprequests: QueryGrouprequestsOverloadI = async (
  variables: ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
  limit: number = Infinity,
  returnPartion = false
) => {
  let res = await queryFunction<
    ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
    ListGrouprequestsQuery
  >(listGrouprequests, variables)
  if (returnPartion) return res.listGrouprequests
  let result = [...res.listGrouprequests.items]

  if (result.length >= limit) return result
  while (res.listGrouprequests.nextToken) {
    res = await queryFunction<
      ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
      ListGrouprequestsQuery
    >(listGrouprequests, {
      ...variables,
      nextToken: res.listGrouprequests.nextToken,
    })
    result = [...result, ...res.listGrouprequests.items]
    if (result.length >= limit) return result
  }
  return result
}
```

This is my `ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables`

```
export type ListGrouprequestsQuery = {
  listGrouprequests?:  {
    __typename: "ModelGrouprequestConnection",
    items:  Array< {
      __typename: "Grouprequest",
      id: string,
      requesterId: string,
      groupId: string,
      consent_end?: string | null,
      consent_start?: string | null,
      meteringpoint: string,
      isRemoved?: boolean | null,
      removedDate?: string | null,
      meteringpointid: string,
      consumption?: boolean | null,
      consentId?: string | null,
      generation_type?: Generationtypes | null,
      splitting_active?: string | null,
      splitting_new?: string | null,
      data_completed?: string | null,
      status: Userstatus,
      process_protocol?:  Array< {
        __typename: "Protocolitem",
        date: string,
        message_type: string,
        message: string,
        response_code: string,
      } | null > | null,
      e_producer_item_id?: number | null,
      e_product_item_id?: number | null,
      e_product_id?: number | null,
      e_monthly_product_item_id?: number | null,
      e_monthly_product_id?: number | null,
      e_initial_product_id?: number | null,
      e_initial_product_item_id?: number | null,
      e_meteringpoint_id?: number | null,
      hasIndividualPrice?: boolean | null,
      new_monthly_cost_date?: string | null,
      new_initial_cost_date?: string | null,
      new_price_date?: string | null,
      new_initial_cost?: number | null,
      new_monthly_cost?: number | null,
      new_price?: number | null,
      process?: Prozessstatus | null,
      createdAt: string,
      updatedAt: string,
    } | null >,
    nextToken?: string | null,
  } | null,
};
```

The error i receive is:

> Type '(variables: ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables, limit?: number,
> returnPartion?: boolean) => Promise<{ __typename:
> "ModelGrouprequestConnection"; items: { ...; }[]; nextToken?: string;
> } | { ...; }[]>' is not assignable to type
> 'QueryGrouprequestsOverloadI'.   Type 'Promise<{ __typename:
> "ModelGrouprequestConnection"; items: { __typename: "Grouprequest";
> id: string; requesterId: string; groupId: string; consent_end?:
> string; consent_start?: string; meteringpoint: string; ... 28 more
> ...; updatedAt: string; }[]; nextToken?: string; } | { ...; }[]>' is
> not assignable to type 'Promise<{ __typename: "Grouprequest"; id:
> string; requesterId: string; groupId: string; consent_end?: string;
> consent_start?: string; meteringpoint: string; isRemoved?: boolean;
> removedDate?: string; ... 26 more ...; updatedAt: string; }[]>'.
> Type '{ __typename: "ModelGrouprequestConnection"; items: { __typename: "Grouprequest"; id: string; requesterId: string; groupId: string; consent_end?: string; consent_start?: string; meteringpoint:
> string; ... 28 more ...; updatedAt: string; }[]; nextToken?: string; }
> | { ...; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ __typename: "Grouprequest";
> id: string; requesterId: string; groupId: string; consent_end?:
> string; consent_start?: string; meteringpoint: string; isRemoved?:
> boolean; removedDate?: string; meteringpointid: string; ... 25 more
> ...; updatedAt: string; }[]'.
> Type '{ __typename: "ModelGrouprequestConnection"; items: { __typename: "Grouprequest"; id: string; requesterId: string; groupId: string; consent_end?: string; consent_start?: string; meteringpoint:
> string; ... 28 more ...; updatedAt: string; }[]; nextToken?: string;
> }' is missing the following properties from type '{ __typename:
> "Grouprequest"; id: string; requesterId: string; groupId: string;
> consent_end?: string; consent_start?: string; meteringpoint: string;
> isRemoved?: boolean; removedDate?: string; meteringpointid: string;
> ... 25 more ...; updatedAt: string; }[]': length, pop, push, concat,
> and 29 more.ts(2322)

So, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

**How to fix?**

The error message you get can be useful in seeing the problem but its too big currently. Simplify this into a smaller version with less variables and add each one incrementally to find the problem.

**Remove**

Also - you don't need to supply: *ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables* here, because its already determined in your *queryGrouprequestsOverloadI*

```
 export const queryGrouprequests: QueryGrouprequestsOverloadI = async (
  variables: ListGrouprequestsQueryVariables,
  limit: number = Infinity,
  returnPartion = false
)
```

Replace with:

```
 export const queryGrouprequests: QueryGrouprequestsOverloadI = async (
  variables,
  limit = Infinity,
  returnPartion = false
)
```